# How does Return works in a VB.net sub?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to understand how the following sub work,

```
Private Shared Sub checkManagerAPI()
        manager = New ManagerConnection(ASTERISK_HOST, ASTERISK_PORT, ASTERISK_LOGINNAME, ASTERISK_LOGINPWD)
        manager.RegisterUserEventClass(GetType(UserAgentLoginEvent))
        AddHandler manager.UserEvents, New EventHandler(Of UserEvent)(AddressOf dam_UserEvents)
        AddHandler manager.NewExten, New EventHandler(Of NewExtenEvent)(AddressOf manager_IgnoreEvent)
        AddHandler manager.UnhandledEvent, New EventHandler(Of ManagerEvent)(AddressOf dam_Events)
        manager.FireAllEvents = True
        manager.PingInterval = 0

        Try
            manager.Login()
            Console.WriteLine("Asterisk version : " & manager.Version)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
            Console.ReadLine()
            manager.Logoff()
            Return
        End Try
```

I have always used Return in a function, can someone explain what it does here (the second to last line), does it restart the sub in case of an error?
Thanks

Comment: Return does always the same thing. Exits from the Sub. But in this case, if there are no more lines after the End Try you could omit it. You could have searched for it easily https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/return-statement

Comment: Thanks much, I did search but unfortunately all I was seeing was about functions.

Comment: Sub or Function doesn't matter. Of course when exiting from a Function you are required to return a value of the required type defined in the Function entry point

Comment: **[Return Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/return-statement)**

Comment: He just wanted to make *extra* sure that his exception handling code does not do anything more that what he wrote.  That started with the LogOff() call.  Exception handling tends to be black magic to programmers, primarily because it is code that is very hard to test.  So while it make no sense at all it is actually self-documenting code.  You know he doesn't quite understand Try/Catch and did not test it.  Beware, dragons live there.

Comment: If you are unsure about returning from a `Sub` (which by definition isn't returning anything) use `Exit Sub` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a Sub or Set procedure, the Return statement is equivalent to an
>   Exit Sub or Exit Property statement, and expression must not be
>   supplied.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/return-statement)